# PostgreSQL JDBC PreparedStatement's setBytes changes parameter value

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have PostgreSQL table that contains a `bytea` column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   text_col text NOT NULL,
   bytea_col bytea NOT NULL
);
```

The insert into the table uses a `PreparedStatement` something like this:

```
...
byte[] value = "ABC".getBytes();
String insertStmt = "INSERT INTO my_table (text_col, bytea_col) VALUES (?, ?)";    
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insertStmt);
ps.setString(1, "SomeString");
ps.setBytes(2, value);
...
```

When the byte[] for the string `ABC` is printed it is: `[65 66 67]`.
However, when I look at the inserted value in the database it is: `\x414243` which, I assume, is equivalent to a byte[] of `[41 42 43]`.

Therefore, when I do a query using `[65 66 67]` in my WHERE clause, the row is never found.

```
select * from my_table where bytes_col = E'\\x656667';
```

Does the `setBytes` in the `PreparedStatement` change the bytes that I pass in? This seems wrong. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I look at the inserted value in the database it is: \x414243 which, I assume, is equivalent to a byte[] of [41 42 43]

That would be a faulty assumption.  The `\x` indicates that the data are presented in hexadecimal format.  Thus `\x414243` is equivalent to a `byte[]` of `[ 0x41, 0x42, 0x43 ]`.  In decimal, that's `[ 65, 66, 67 ]`, and in any base those are the ASCII codes for 'A', 'B', and 'C'.  Your data are stored correctly.  Your query for it is incorrect.